# As seen in the image, create two responsive DIVs with space between them

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, mobile-website

[image: To further understand my demand, click on this link and look at the image.]

I'm working on a codewell challenge and I'm stuck on this portion. I can't make an even space between them, and the images are overlapping.

```css
.website {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="website">
  <div class="spense">
    <img id="spense" src="./Assets/Spense.png" alt="spense">
    <h3>Spense.com<img class="arrow" src="./Assets/noun-arrow-2841221-svg.png" alt="arrow-icon"></h3>
    Rethinking the way writers get paid, an open resource platform <br> design to help writers focus more on writing, and less on <br> when and how they'll get paid, Projects in collaboration with <br> Codewell.cc
  </div>
  <div class="yelp">
    <img id="yelp" src="./Assets/YelpCamp.png" alt="YelpCamp">
    <h3>YelpCamp.com<img class="arrow" src="./Assets/noun-arrow-2841221-svg.png" alt="arrow-icon"></h3>
    Allowing backpack travelers to perfectly plan their trip <br> through an open-source platform similar to TripAdvisor. With <br>over 1m MAU, YelpCamp has been the crowd's favorite in <br>2021.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not inspect the markup of that other website to see how they resolved it?

Comment: They provide png files for website design.

Comment: What about https://chrisinabit.github.io/landingpage/? Besides the fonts, this looks like the stuff in your image

Comment: I looked at the link you provided. The text, on the other hand, is eluding it. I'd want to create a div and place the image and text within it so that they're both the same width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use width property on each child inside flex container.

```css
.website {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.spense, .yelp{
  width:40%;
}
.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1rem;
}
.image{
width:100%;
object-fit:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="website">
  <div class="spense">
    <img class="image" id="spense" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="spense">
    <h3>Spense.com<img class="arrow" src="./Assets/noun-arrow-2841221-svg.png" alt="arrow-icon"></h3>
    Rethinking the way writers get paid, an open resource platform <br> design to help writers focus more on writing, and less on <br> when and how they'll get paid, Projects in collaboration with <br> Codewell.cc
  </div>
  <div class="yelp">
    <img class="image" id="yelp" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt="YelpCamp">
    <h3>YelpCamp.com<img class="arrow" src="./Assets/noun-arrow-2841221-svg.png" alt="arrow-icon"></h3>
    Allowing backpack travelers to perfectly plan their trip <br> through an open-source platform similar to TripAdvisor. With <br>over 1m MAU, YelpCamp has been the crowd's favorite in <br>2021.
  </div>
```

Comment: But, I do not want any space at the start or end.

Comment: Then what's the issue in your implementation? You want space between those two elements. In the question, you said I want evenly space. 
You can set max width of the parent container if you want.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vhLQqSC38GhNRputfWoeGv0Zqe42v4mN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The image's URL has been provided; notice how there is more room in the center.

Comment: please check the updated snippet

Comment: Thank you very much for your help; it was really appreciated.

Comment: if you think this solved your problems please mark it as accepted answer so that others know it has been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify a `width` for divs:

```css
.website {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1rem;
}
#spense,#yelp{
  width: 100%;
}
.spense,.yelp{
   width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="website">
  <div class="spense">
    <img id="spense" src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/1-6-5_ssnb.jpg" alt="spense">
    <h3>Spense.com<img class="arrow" src="./Assets/noun-arrow-2841221-svg.png" alt="arrow-icon"></h3>
    Rethinking the way writers get paid, an open resource platform <br> design to help writers focus more on writing, and less on <br> when and how they'll get paid, Projects in collaboration with <br> Codewell.cc
  </div>
  <div class="yelp">
    <img id="yelp" src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/1-6-5_ssnb.jpg" alt="YelpCamp">
    <h3>YelpCamp.com<img class="arrow" src="./Assets/noun-arrow-2841221-svg.png" alt="arrow-icon"></h3>
    Allowing backpack travelers to perfectly plan their trip <br> through an open-source platform similar to TripAdvisor. With <br>over 1m MAU, YelpCamp has been the crowd's favorite in <br>2021.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use ,
justify content to space-evenly instead! and that should work

Comment: Provide some code that support your answer.